# InstallShield installs to SysWOW64 and not in System32

Tags: installshield, windows-7-x64, installshield-2012

I'm creating a InstallShield 2012 Spring project, and I need to copy some jpg into System32 subfolder.
In Application Data/Files and Folders, I put that into [WindowsFolder]/System32/akrmf and when install, it copies to SysWOW64/akrmf on Windows 7
The installation project doesn't include any exe or dll, only text files and images.
I tried using [SystemFolder] and copies into SysWOW64 too.

Is there any way to force installation into System32/akrmf folder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target the true (64-bit) system folder with [Windows Installer](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/Targeting64Bit-MSI.htm), your MSI needs to be a 64-bit package (see [Targeting 64-bit Operating Systems](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelp64BitSupport.htm)). Unfortunately this prevents it from installing on 32-bit systems.

To do this with [InstallScript](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/Targeting64Bit-IS.htm), there are related approaches that do not require creating two separate packages, but you may find it easiest to create two different components where only one is selected for installation.